# How to call lambda inside the __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

My big application involves few codes like this:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.destroy= lambda num=num : self.destroywidgets(num)

def destroywidgets(self,num):
    if num == 1:
        for widget in self.frame1.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    elif num == 2:
        for widget in self.frame2.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    elif num == 3:
        for widget in self.frame3.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

def func1(self):
    self.destroy(1)
```

This is the small picture of my code. But when I run this code, I am getting below error:

```
self.destroy= lambda num=num : self.destroywidgets(num)
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

I am really confused as this code was running successfully the previous day. This is throwing such error after restart today. Why is this behaviour?
Please note that, I tried altering this lambda in multiple ways and referred to many SOF answers, still couldn't resolve it.

Also, please tell me if this could be done using partial(functools).

To make it understand better, below is the smaller snippet I made:

```
num = ""

def paint(num):
    if num == 1:
        return "1st paint - green"
    elif num == 2:
        return "1st paint - blue"
    elif num == 3:
        return "1st paint - red"
    else:
        return "no more options"

op = lambda num = num : paint(num)

print(op(2))
print(op(3))
print(op(4))
```

And I get the perfect output as below:

```
1st paint - blue
1st paint - red
no more options
```

But why isn't this working in above code?

Comment: Was it running on python2 before?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I am running in Py3 only since I started building this app

Comment: What exactly is `num` supposed to be?

Comment: @Nae "num" is an arg that does which statement of lambda to be executed

Comment: shouldn't this just be `self.destroy= lambda num : self.destroywidgets(num)` ?

Comment: You only write `lambda num=num:` if you have an existing `num` value that you want to use as the default value for the `num` parameter. (This is confusing in the general case, but there are a few special cases where it's useful—capturing a variable's value at function creation time, optimizing a global lookup by copying it to locals, etc.)

Comment: Also, the question title asks how to _call_ a lambda in the `__init__`. Surely you don't want to call this function here, just define it, right?

Comment: well.. after the edit, in the second example `num` exists as a variable, you initialize it. It does not happen inside your `__init__`  function. This comes to confirm what @abarnert was saying.

Comment: @jaumebonet Yeah!! I tried that too. And I encounter below error:

for c in list(self.children.values()): c.destroy()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'

Comment: @abarnert I am trying to understand you. Can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: There was no way to be elaborate enough in a comment, so I wrote an answer.

Comment: I _may_ have guessed wrong about what you're trying to do, but please read it and tell me.

Comment: I just defined  'num=""' just before calling 'self.destroy= lambda num=num : self.destroywidgets(num)' and this is working normally and solves my issue. But what I thought is anything inside __init__ should be defined globally.

Comment: @cs2612 `__init__`  is supposed to be use to initialize the attributes of an instance of a class. Thus, it will define the attributes that are globally accessible to the class (through `self.attr`). If you are talking about global script/library variables, they should be used sparsely and with care.

Answer (score 1):

Before we even get into fixing this:

What you want is for `self.destroy` to be a function that can be called with a `num` and will call `self.destroywidgets` with that `num`. In other words, you just want it to be `self.destroywidgets`. So:

```
self.destroy = self.destroywidgets
```

Creating a lambda that does nothing but pass its arguments through to another function is just a more verbose and slow way of doing the same thing as that other function.

---

In fact, there's an even simpler solution here. Get rid of `__init__`, and just do this at the class level:

```
destroy = destroywidgets
```

… because all you're effectively doing is providing another name for the same method that works the same way.

---

But meanwhile, why does your existing code not work? Let's look at it again:

```
self.destroy = lambda num=num: self.destroywidgets(num)
```

Sometimes `lambda` can be confusing, so let's rewrite it as `def`:

```
def destroy(num=num):
    self.destroywidgets(num)
self.destroy=destroy
```

Now, that's actually legal syntax. It means basically the same as this:<sup>*</sup>

```
def destroy(num2=num):
    self.destroywidgets(num2)
self.destroy=destroy
```

But you have to have a local or global variable named `num` whose value you want to use as the default value for the parameter. And you have no such variable. And not because of anything wrong with the way your code is ordered; there really is nothing obvious you could use here. And, fortunately, you don't *need* a default value. When you call the function, you pass in a value, `1`.

So, if you wanted to fix your existing code, you could just do this:

```
self.destroy = lambda num: self.destroywidgets(num)
```

But again, you're better off just using `self.destroywidget` instead of wrapping it in a useless lambda.

---

<sub>* It's generally confusing using the same name for the parameter and the variable you get its default value from, but it's legal because there are a few good uses for it. For example, it's the idiomatic way to capture the current value of a closure variable at function definition time, instead of capturing the variable itself.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So I have make it work like this:

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.destroy= lambda num : self.destroywidgets(num)

  def destroywidgets(self,num):
    if num == 1:
        print 1
    elif num == 2:
        print 2
    elif num == 3:
        print 3

  def func1(self):
    self.destroy(1)

  def func2(self):
    self.destroy(2)

a = Test(1)
a.func1()
# 1
a.func2()
# 2
```

The only issue here is that I don't get where the `master` attribute goes, but this solution allows for the `self.destroy` function to be created and reply to the input number

Comment: This may not raise any exceptions, but I doubt it's what he wants. First, why take a `num` parameter only to ignore it like this? Second, your code requires an argument to the constructor, which his code doesn't have, and it's not clear what that argument should mean or where he should get its value.

Comment: no no... you are right... this is not ok... I oversimplified the problem... I'm trying to see what did I miss.

Comment: At this point we're just guessing at what he's trying to do. I may be just as wrong, I just don't yet know enough to have any idea whether I am. :)

Comment: agreed! After edit, it should at least behave so that `self.destroy` acts according to the provided attribute. I'm a little confused on why not just declare `destroy` as a regular object function though, but this is as far as I can get with the info we have.

Comment: Well, `destroy` is an attribute that acts like a method even though it isn't, and in fact acts exactly like the `destroywidgets` method, so the real question is, why have it at all? (If it's needed because some other API he has no control over is going to call it, the simplest way to fix that is `destroy = destroywidgets` at the class level.)

Comment: It is not a very intuitive thing to do. I actually think it would probably be enough for him to do as you say and just assign the function at class level.